# Conditional include EF with children

Tags: entity-framework, linq

According to this article: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/10/12/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include/#comment-5225

I learned how to do a conditional include.

But now I need some lower level children like if a review has Marks, I need to fetch for each review the collection of Marks also. Any idea how to do this?

Query:

```
 var movie = readOnlyRepository.GetById<Movie>(
                    movieId, false);
 var dbquery = from mv in movie
                 select new
                 {
                     mv,
                     reviews = from review in mv.Reviews
                     where review.Mark = 10
                     select review
                 };


var result = dbquery.AsEnumerable().Select(x=> x.mv).First();
```

Given that Review has a collection of Marks I need that included in the result.

Comment: can you show your query ?

Comment: @Sampath please see update

Comment: still your question is not giving enough details.where you have `lower lever children like if a review has Marks` on your query.can you change that wording according to your real example ?

Comment: Just continue with anonymous type selects, i.e. instead of `select review`, use `select new { review, marks = review.Marks }` etc.

Comment: tried this also. For some reason not even review is completed in my Movie.